# Swift in Xcode pageViewController not changing page when swiping

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I have a pageViewController in swift in Xcode. I followed a tutorial to make a pageViewController that you can swipe and change from page to page. Mine does not do that. Here is my code for the pageViewController.

```
class MainMenue: UIPageViewController {


private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.newViewController(number: "1"), self.newViewController(number: "2")]
}()

private func newViewController(number:String)-> UIViewController{

    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Menu\(number)")


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource = self

    if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
        setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0  else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
    let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count

    guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else{
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]

}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


}

extension MainMenue: UIPageViewControllerDataSource{


public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    return nil
}



public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{

    return nil
}

}
```

The only thing that I did differently than the tutorial was that I only used 2 view controllers instead of 3. This is the tutorial I followed. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/